# XGBoost Model Save Failed

Tags: scala, xgboost

XGBoost Verison: 0.90
Apache Spark Version : 2.4.4

XGBoost training seems to be complete but when trying to save the model, it fails with below error

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse(Lorg/json4s/JsonInput;Z)Lorg/json4s/JsonAST$JValue;
        at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.params.DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$3.apply(DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter.scala:73)
        at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.params.DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$3.apply(DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter.scala:71)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.params.DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter$$anonfun$1.apply(DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter.scala:71)
        at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.params.DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter$$anonfun$1.apply(DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter.scala:69)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.params.DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter$.getMetadataToSave(DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter.scala:69)
        at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.params.DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter$.saveMetadata(DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter.scala:51)
        at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostRegressionModel$XGBoostRegressionModelWriter.saveImpl(XGBoostRegressor.scala:421)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLWriter.save(ReadWrite.scala:180)

Code Piece :

val xgboostRegressionModel = xgboostRegressor.fit(transformedDS)
xgboostRegressionModel.write.overwrite().save(map.get("model_ouputpath").get + "/" + map.get("XGBoost_model_name").get)

Comment: I am not sure about the error. Maybe you can do it the easy by just pickling the model. Won't that work?

Comment: Yeah that's there. But actually the code is handled in a different way. The training of the model and the testing of model is part of oozie workflow and are in different actions.